# Install linux headers 4.12 on Kali 2017.2

Tags: kali-linux

I installed the 32-bit release of Kali 2017.2 without issue:

```
# uname -r
4.12.0-kali1-686-pae
```

I want to install `linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-686-pae`, but I can't find or install it:

```
# apt-cache search linux-headers
....
aufs-dkms - DKMS files to build and install aufs
linux-headers-4.13.0-kali1-686 - Header files for Linux 4.13.0-kali1-686
linux-headers-4.13.0-kali1-686-pae - Header files for Linux 4.13.0-kali1-686-pae
linux-headers-4.13.0-kali1-all - All header files for Linux 4.13 (meta-package)
linux-headers-4.13.0-kali1-all-i386 - All header files for Linux 4.13 (meta-package)
linux-headers-4.13.0-kali1-common - Common header files for Linux 4.13.0-kali1
linux-headers-686 - Header files for Linux 686 configuration (meta-package)
linux-headers-686-pae - Header files for Linux 686-pae configuration (meta-package)
linux-libc-dev-alpha-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-arm64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
...
```

This is my repo address:

```
# cat /etc/apt/source*
deb https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

How can I install `linux-headers-4.12...` on Kali 2017.2 without upgrading it?

I don't want to upgrade my OS, I want to install only `linux-headers-4.12...`, and I don't want to run `apt upgrade` on my system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to download the packages manually from [the pool](http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/), while they’re still available (as I write this, the versions you’re after are still there).

Presumably you’re aware that your kernel has a number of known vulnerabilities...

Comment: seems like the mentioned package is now no longer available from the pool. any idea where i may find archived `linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1*.deb`?

Comment: I have no idea... It’s time to move on really.

Comment: while 'move on' sounds good it somewhat renders the use of kali as a live-os into a quite limited solution as some tools or programs need these headers to function properly (say hypervisors, ...). non persistent systems cannot reboot into 4.13 after updating. i'd recommend to edit your accepted solution to reflect the packages are no longer present as it doesn't really solve the OPs issue any more.

Comment: Does Kali Live still use 4.12?

Comment: the 17.2 snapshot which is the official latest stable release according to https://www.kali.org/downloads/ comes with kernel 4.12, so yes it does. one solution (at least for some) might be to use the unstable weekly builds, yet i was hoping to be able to use the stable release until the next official one is released...

Comment: That suggests that Kali should be keeping the corresponding packages available then — it’s rather surprising to ship a live system using a given version, without making the corresponding packages available in the repositories. I recommend taking it up with them.

Answer (score 1):

**You will need to download the .deb package containing the Linux headers from the pool directory in [kali repo web site](http://http.kali.org/kali).**

Download the package from the kali repository:

```
wget http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-686-pae_4.12.6-1kali6_i386.deb
```

Use apt to install the package:

```
apt install ./linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-686-pae_4.12.6-1kali6_i386.deb
```

After you can clean up:

```
rm ./linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-686-pae_4.12.6-1kali6_i386.deb
```

[here](http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/) is a direct link if you need a different package for your situation.